# Java : call child class method from parent class using interface

Tags: java, android, parent-child

I don't know if this question is valid or I am doing something wrong with defining the parent class structure.

But the following are the formation of the classes and interface are.

```
public interface Test {
    public void print();
    public void write();
}

class Parent implements Test{
    @Override
        public void print() {
            System.out.print("This is parent class");
    }

    @Override
        public void write() {
            System.out.print("This is write method in parent class");
    }
 }

class Child extends Parent{
    @Override
    public void print(){
        System.out.print("This is child class);
    }
}
```

Expected output when I call method using the interface

```
Test test = new Parent();
test.print();
```

It should call print method from the Child class.

And when I call method using interface

```
Test test = new Parent();
test.write();
```

It should call write method from the Parent class.

So right now it's not happening, in both the cases it's calling the method from the Parent class.

So any suggestion or answer are much appreciated.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the code you use to initialize `test`? In particular, is its type `Child` or `Parent`?

Comment: `when I call method using the interface` how do you call it?

Comment: Can you edit your question to show how you are instanciating the classes?

Comment: Can you add a [MCVE]? With how you initialize your objects and how you call the methods. Unrelated but you wrote that `Parent` override the method `write` but it's not declared in the interface.

Comment: @HassamAbdelillah I have edited my questions to init the Test interface using the Parent class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using:

```
Test test = new Parent();
test.write();
```

your `test` is of type `Parent` and is unaware of `Child`. Hence your output indicates both methods on the `Parent` class are called.

Try:

```
Test test = new Child();
test.print();   // Will call Child::print()
test.write();   // Will call Parent::write()
```

and you should achieve what you want.

**N.B.** For this to work, you must add `write()` to your `Test` interface, thus:

```
public interface Test {
    public void print();
    public void write(); // This is required for it to be accessible via the interface
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need to cast it to the `Child` class. Maybe put a check before it like this:

```
if (test instanceof Child) {
    ((Child) test).print();
}
```

Comment: It is reasonable to know how he is instanciating test before ever proposing any solution :)

Answer (score 0):

The output makes sense because you are creating (instanciating) an objet of type `Parent`.

Naturally, your `write()` and `print()` will follow the `Parent` implementation and therefore display :

```
This is write method in parent class
```

and

```
This is parent class
```

You have to create Child instance to use in same fashion it's `write()` and `print()` implementations :

```
Test test = new Child();
test.write();
test.print();
```

this piece of code will display what you expected. Since `write()` has no `Child` implementation it would display the `Parent` message

Comment: `Test test = new Child()` would make it more clear.